# WPF library similar to jQuery UI?

Tags: wpf, jquery-ui, wpf-controls, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-resizable

Are there any WPF libraries similar to [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)?

I especially like the [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#portlets) interaction:

[image]

and [Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) interaction:

[image]

Would be great if these 2 interactions could be combined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The panels are just an Expander in WPF world, as far as I can see. To make them "Sortable" you need to create a custom panel that works like a wrap panel and hosts Expanders, and add drag and drop functionality. Shouldn't be too hard to do, but I haven't seen one around (at least in free / open-source components).